# How to parse Gmail chat logs from webpage?

Tags: html, xpath, gmail, chat, logging

What would be the best way to parse Gmail chat logs from the webpage where it's displayed?  As far as I know, this is still the only way to access server-hosted Gmail chat logs (through either desktop Gmail or mobile Gmail).

When looking at the generated source where the conversation takes place, the markup looks like nested divs and spans (and the divs elsewhere on the page have randomized two-character ids and classes with no pattern).  Here's an excerpt from a line that has a timestamp to the left:

```
<div>
<span style="display:block;float:left;color:#888">
2:56 PM&nbsp;
</span>

<span style="display:block;padding-left:6em">
<span>

<span style="font-weight:bold">me</span>: i'm trying to think of a good way to parse gmail chat logs

</span>
</span>
</div>
```

But not every line has a timestamp, so those without one seem to place nonbreaking spaces in its place:

```
<div>
<span style="display:block;float:left;color:#888">
&nbsp;&nbsp;
</span>

<span style="display:block;padding-left:6em">

<span>
and reformat that into something like an xml format
</span>

</span>
</div>
```

Should I use XPath?  Is there something more efficient?

Edit:

As data only, this is what it looks like:

```
12:43 AM John: Something something something.
         Something something something.
         me: Something something something?
12:44 AM Also, something something something.
12:47 AM Something something something.
12:48 AM Something something something
         with something something something.
12:49 AM John: Something.
```

Comment: You forgot to mention which nodes you want to select?

Comment: I'd want to grab the names, the conversation lines, and the timestamps.

So every line will possibly be [time] [name] [something said], where time is optional and name is filled in wherever not explicitly written.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I use XPath? Is there something
>   more efficient?

I would use Ruby with the Nokogiri library, it gives you much more flexibility than just XPath/XSLT:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

src = <<EOS
<div>
    <span style="display:block;float:left;color:#888">
        2:56 PM&nbsp;
    </span>
    <span style="display:block;padding-left:6em">
        <span>
            <span style="font-weight:bold">me</span>: i'm trying to think of a good way to parse gmail chat logs
        </span>
    </span>
    <span style="display:block;float:left;color:#888">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
    </span>
    <span style="display:block;padding-left:6em">
        <span>
            and reformat that into something like an xml format
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
EOS

chatlog = []
last_timestamp = nil
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(src)

doc.xpath('//div/span').each do |span|
    style = span.attributes['style'].value

    if style.include?('color:')
        last_timestamp = span.content.strip
    elsif style.include?('padding-left:')
        chatlog << {:timestamp => last_timestamp, :message => span.content.strip}
    end
end

builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |doc|
    doc.chatlog {
        chatlog.each do |line|
            doc.line {
                doc.time    line[:timestamp]
                doc.message line[:message]
            }
        end
    }
end
```

Returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<chatlog>
  <line>
    <time>2:56 PM </time>
    <message>me: i'm trying to think of a good way to parse gmail chat logs</message>
  </line>
  <line>
    <time>  </time>
    <message>and reformat that into something like an xml format</message>
  </line>
</chatlog>
```